# Visual Studio Code - navigation bar path

Tags: path, code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZSU.jpg)How to set up this kind of navigation bar - where u can click on catalogs like in windows systems. Tis video and "GPS" icon on the top left: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTRZYnYQlmo&list=PLRRRJQrU_ZTf2KibYb_58-59SQJy1y1DE&index=5&t=199s

I can not find it in application.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You probably want to post a picture and more detailed request of what you are looking for rather than asking people to view a YouTube video to figure out how to answer your question.

Comment: How can i add picture in comment?

Comment: Edit your original question (use the edit button below the question text). Include a picture and more details about what you are looking for

Comment: i did it and do not see my screen :)

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZSU.jpg